# Обращение к свойству объекта с @ в имени

Tags: php, json, парсер, объекты

Добрый день уважаемое сообщество!

Имеется объект, полученный в результате парсинга JSON строки, вот кусочек:

```
  "@n":"0",
  "info":{  
     "@customerdate":"20180326T00:00:00",
     "@doctype":"m",
     "@export":"Crrm",
     "@fldc":"C",
     "@flinfo":"r",
     "@number":"ПН507364З",
```

Вопрос в том, как обратиться с помощью PHP например к свойству @number, следующие попытки потерпели неудачу :)

```
info->number
info->@number
info->\@number
```

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим изначальный JSON:

```
$data = '{"@n":"0",
          "info":{  
            "@customerdate":"20180326T00:00:00",
            "@doctype":"m",
            "@export":"Crrm",
            "@fldc":"C",
            "@flinfo":"r",
            "@number":"ПН507364З"
          }
        }';
$json = json_decode($data); // JSON декодированный в stdClass
```

Обращение к полю `@number` будет выглядить так:

```
echo $json->info->{'@number'};
```

Comment: Спасибо! Завелось))